# Handling diffferent number of observations at timepoints

Tags: python, gpflow

I am working with a data set that contains at different number of observations at different time points. For example, at x(0), 2 observations are available while at x(1) 4 observations are available.
Is there a principled way of dealing with this data in gpflow?
Much thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you mean observations of different quantities (e.g., at x(0) you measure temperature and pressure, at x(1) you measure those but also wind speed and rainfall)? or just multiple observations (e.g. at x(0) you measured temperature twice, at x(1) you measured it four times)?

Comment: Please provide a sample of the data-set!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're talking about observations of different quantities, you can do this using the "output-as-input" model, where we add an extra column to the input that specifies for which output we provide the observation. For example, your feature and target arrays might look as follows:

```py
X = np.array([
    [x[0], 0],
    [x[0], 1],
    [x[1], 0],
    [x[1], 1],
    [x[1], 2],
    [x[1], 3],
])
Y = np.array([
    [y0_0],
    [y0_1],
    [y1_0],
    [y1_1],
    [y1_2],
    [y1_3],
])
```

and then use the `Coregion` kernel, see [the coregionalisation notebook](https://gpflow.readthedocs.io/en/master/notebooks/advanced/coregionalisation.html).